# Determine the largest positive integer $k$ such that $\chi(H)=\chi(G)=k$

Tags: graph-theory

> Determine the largest positive integer $k$ such that $\chi(H)=\chi(G)=k$, where $H$ is obtained from a nonempty graph $G$ by subdividing each edge of $G$ exactly once.

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$, size $m$ and $\chi(G)=k$. Let $p$ be the number of vertices of degree 2 that is inserted into the edges of $G$, then

$n_H= n+mp$ and $m_H =m+p$.

I also know that $1 \leq \chi(G) \leq n$ and $1 \leq \chi(H) \leq n+mp$.

We want $\chi(H)=\chi(G)=k$, so the largest $k$ is $k=n+mp$? Am I correct? I'm not very good at  problem like this.

Comment: Well, at least you found an upper bound on $k$ (though I must say that bound is trivial).  But, are you sure this is the largest $k$ ?  I mean, can you find a $G$ such that $H$ has chromatic number $n + mp$?  I believe $H$ is always easier to color than that.  As a hint, look at the cycles of $G$.  What happens to these cycles in $G$ ?  What can you say about the cycles of $H$ ?

Comment: for each cycle of $G$, the length of the cycle of $H$ is twice the length of the cycle of $G$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif By a subdivision, you mean adding only one extra vertex to each edge right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any graph $G$, by subdividing every edge, we insert one vertex per edge to obtain $H$. Say the vertices of $G$ are colored black. If one colors the new degree $2$ vertices introduced as red, it is easy to see that $H$ is a bipartite graph; hence $\chi(H)$ is always $2$, no matter what $\chi(G)$ is. So $k=2$.